# Heuristics for lightweight ways for how to tell if two html pages are the same "page"

Tags: comparison, html

I know similar questions have already been asked, but I want to know whether there exists some code\package, or some ideas on how to tell if two urls are the same page.

For motivation, assume that what I want to do is write a chrome extension that tells you how many of your facebook friends visited a link.

Of course simply comparing urls won't work as some url parameters might be critical while other are not, e.g `google.com?query=help` is not the same page as `google.com?query=idea` as the `query` parameter is critical, while `google.com?referrer=facebook` is the same as `google.com?referrer=twitter` (I am of course making up these examples).

Also, comparing the page's content is not guaranteed to work, as if there are randomized parts ("related stories") or user-specific content (headline of "Hi Noam, we haven't seen you in a while").

Of course, I am not looking for a foolproof method, just something that work on most normal-behaving sites.

Any good recommendations of packages (any language) or ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just compare the text of the websites....

Comment: @ColeJohnson - See what I wrote near the end: Also, comparing the page's content is not guaranteed to work, as if there are randomized parts ("related stories") or user-specific content (headline of "Hi Noam, we haven't seen you in a while").
From experience, in a lot of cases two instances of the same page might be very similar but not exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Any standard distance metric on string comparisons should give you a score for various URLs' contents. Presumably, contents that are more similar will have better scores than less similar URLs, so rank results and compare.

Comment: I thought about that, but does it fall under the "lightweight" category? Again, I do not want to create a chrome extension that has a heavy toll on the CPU - no one likes that kind of extensions :)
EDIT: I want to stress again that I do not need a foolproof algorithm, any heuristic that'll work on most pages will do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make sure that two pages are the same. There may be user-specific content (Login Buttons for some users, a personal greeting for others), advertising, browser-specific content (CSS3 for Chrome, CSS2 for Opera, a drive-by-download-exploit for IE6 users :))

The same resource may be available under different URLs (`/article/4-funny-ways-to-encrypt-your-shellcode-123456` or `/article.php?id=123456`). There might my two domains for the same content (`www.domain.com` and `domain.com`, maybe even `domain.co.uk`). You could get some clues from the `Last-Modified:` header which might contain the file modification date, but when it comes to dynamic content, it can also contain the generation date. There may be a `ETag` header that contains a hash for the underlying resource, at least in ruby on rails, if correctly implemented, which is not often the case.

So the only thing left you could probably do is to compare so pages and calculate some metrics. I would consider the domain, IP address and page content for comparision. With a higher weight on IP address and domain (or domain fractions). So you can calculate certain probabilites, but there is no way to make sure two pages *are the same*.